# SQL Server Concurrent Queries Slow performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm doing select from a table with about 400 connections on SQL Server, each connection select part of this table and write to a file; the select statement uses the index on the table and each runs independently for 2.5 minutes. When I try to run 400 similar queries with nolock the total query time went up to 40 minutes. Does anyone know where I can optimize to speed up the 400 query to the same speed as running one query?

To explain better here's the example of the queries:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WITH (NOLOCK)  WHERE Id BETWEEN 0 AND 1999999
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WITH (NOLOCK)  WHERE Id BETWEEN 2000000 AND 3999999
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WITH (NOLOCK)  WHERE Id BETWEEN 4000000 AND 5999999
.
.
.
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WITH (NOLOCK)  WHERE Id BETWEEN 710000000 AND 711999999
```

Comment: Try WITH(ROWLOCK) instead. My guess is that those 400 connection are all getting in each other's way, and some locking may give you better performance.

Comment: without monitoring the proccess we are playing a game named "the guessing game", which is really bad idea. First of all you need to monitor the proccess and inform us what is your bottleneck. Are you sure this is the select query and not the IO when you write the files?!? You should monitor waits and locks in he server.

Comment: 1. My first guess (totally a guess with no base) is that the bottleneck is in the writing of the files. Check perfmon and confirm that you actually do not use the max IO of the disk.
2. I assume or at least hope that you have partitions in the table. In this case try to select the data from a single partition in each query (use the same order as the partition key).
3. try to use less connections, according to the number of CPU Cores you have. Next change the number gradually untill you get best performance.

Comment: I can't continue split the steps and tips to 100 short comments and at this time using the current information we have I cannot post something that will be conciser as answer... start with monitoring -> give us more info -> and we will continue from there

Comment: The IO is not maxed out at all, about 10%

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to when you say partition key, it's in sql server and we have index on the ID

Comment: @1EnemyLeft, what about CPU and network utilization?

Comment: can you provide the table definition? and try to avoid `SELECT *`. list the columns you only need. what index do you have on the table?

Comment: I need everything in the table, it's not columnar so I'm guessing the columns doesn't matter here. the index is ID.

Comment: @1EnemyLeft depends on your column list if you are passing multiple LOB datatypes that's a lot of data execution. what type of index on `Id`? clustered or nonclustered? and it's a bit slow that it took 2.5minutes per query. and how big is your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case, you can use **Table Partition** to optimize your query performance. Partitioned table is very much efficient and faster than the only indexed table.
So, create `Partition Schema` and `Partition Function` for the ID column.

Below are the benefits of the partitioned table -

- You can transfer or access subsets of data quickly and efficiently, while maintaining the integrity of a data collection. For example, an operation such as loading data from an OLTP to an OLAP system takes only seconds, instead of the minutes and hours the operation takes when the data is not partitioned.
- You can perform maintenance operations on one or more partitions more quickly. The operations are more efficient because they target only these data subsets, instead of the whole table. For example, you can choose to compress data in one or more partitions or rebuild one or more partitions of an index.
- You may improve query performance, based on the types of queries you frequently run and on your hardware configuration. For example, the query optimizer can process equi-join queries between two or more partitioned tables faster when the partitioning columns in the tables are the same, because the partitions themselves can be joined.

Below links might be helpful for you.

[Partitioned tables and indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)

[How to partition an existing sql server table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2888/how-to-partition-an-existing-sql-server-table/)